# Determine 3rd Party Application Installation Directory in java

Tags: java, filepath

I have inherited a Java application that at one point launches an external application. Currently, the path to said application is hard coded in. One of the first things I want to do is update my newly acquired code to find the install path and use that, rather than hard code it.

Unfortunately, when I search for how to accomplish this, I find only ways to get the install directory *for my application*, rather than *for an external application*.

Essentially, I want the Java equivalent of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309142/determine-3rd-party-application-installation-directory). Is there such a thing, or am I relegated to scraping the registry?

Comment: Most of the application will set an environment variable for their home path, you can access this environment variable and find the application path. `Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
`

Comment: Unfortunately, the application I'm looking for does not put anything in the path variable. This was very interesting information however, and I will definitely use it in the future. I was ultimately able to solve my issue using the JNA library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it's not the best answer - would have preferred a stock Java solution - but without using the reflection hack found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289/read-write-to-windows-registry-using-java), it seems as though there's not much choice. I was able to get the information I needed using [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna).