# File/folder chooser dialog from a Windows batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, dialog, filechooser

In situations where input file location is not known until runtime, using a GUI for file selection input reduces the likelihood of user error.

Is there a way to invoke a file/folder chooser dialog from a Windows batch script?

Answer (score 71):

## File Browser

**Update 2016.3.20:**

Since PowerShell is a native component of all modern Windows installations nowadays, I'm declaring the C# fallback as no longer necessary. If you still need it for Vista or XP compatibility, I moved it to a [new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36156326/1683264). Starting with this edit, I'm rewriting the script as a Batch + PowerShell hybrid and incorporating the ability to perform multi-select. It's profoundly easier to read and to tweak as needed.

```
<# : chooser.bat
:: launches a File... Open sort of file chooser and outputs choice(s) to the console

@echo off
setlocal

for /f "delims=" %%I in ('powershell -noprofile "iex (${%~f0} | out-string)"') do (
    echo You chose %%~I
)
goto :EOF

: end Batch portion / begin PowerShell hybrid chimera #>

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$f = new-object Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
$f.InitialDirectory = pwd
$f.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*"
$f.ShowHelp = $true
$f.Multiselect = $true
[void]$f.ShowDialog()
if ($f.Multiselect) { $f.FileNames } else { $f.FileName }
```

This results in a file chooser dialog.

[image: File chooser dialog]

The result of a selection outputs `You chose C:\Users\me\Desktop\tmp.txt` to the console. If you want to force single file selection, just change the `$f.Multiselect` property to `$false`.

PowerShell taken command from the [Just Tinkering Blog](http://justtinkering.wordpress.com/2011/05/14/use-file-open-dialog-in-powershell/). See the [`OpenFileDialog` Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog) documentation for other properties you can set, such as `Title` and `InitialDirectory`.

## Folder Browser

**Update 2015.08.10:**

Since there is already a COM method for [invoking a folder chooser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15906994/1683264), it's pretty easy to build a PowerShell one-liner that can open the folder chooser and output the path.

```
:: fchooser.bat
:: launches a folder chooser and outputs choice to the console
:: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15885133/1683264

@echo off
setlocal

set "psCommand="(new-object -COM 'Shell.Application')^
.BrowseForFolder(0,'Please choose a folder.',0,0).self.path""

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%I in (`powershell %psCommand%`) do set "folder=%%I"

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
echo You chose !folder!
endlocal
```

In the `BrowseForFolder()` method, the fourth argument specifies the root of the hierarchy. See [ShellSpecialFolderConstants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/shldisp/ne-shldisp-shellspecialfolderconstants) for a list of valid values.

This results in a folder chooser dialog.

[image]

The result of a selection outputs `You chose C:\Users\me\Desktop` to the console.

See the [FolderBrowserDialog class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog) documentation for other properties you can set, such as `RootFolder`. My original .NET `System.Windows.Forms` PowerShell and C# solutions can be found in [revision 4](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/15885133/4) of this answer if needed, but this COM method is much easier to read and maintain.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code! Works just great! One question though. Is there a way to pick multiple files with this method? I've added property f.Multiselect=true and was able to pick multiple files via GUI however it looks like it prints only the first selected file so I can't figure out a way to read all the selected files from the dialog. Do you think it's possible? Or maybe there is another way do pick multiple files with win GUI?

Comment: I feel stupid now :) I had to be a little bit more attentive to the code. So just added foreach(String fileName in f.FileNames^) before Console.Write line to iterate through f.FileNames array to print all the necessary values. Thanks for the code! BTW: printing FileNames array values works for single select mode dialog as well and could be accepted as more generic way to deal with the dialog. Thanks again!

Comment: Really old post but I hope can you show me how you made it  pick multiple files. i wish to accomplish the same thing thanks.

Comment: Thanks highly appreciated working perfectly on windows 7 - 10. the script does not work for windows XP & Vista and I know this is due to it not including powershell. I was wondering if you can alter C# fallback to accomplish your new powershell edit. I tried editing it and it works good multiple select and all but i got stuck at the for loop it echos only 1 file.

Comment: @xNightmare67x Instead of doing `for /f... do set` do `for /f... do echo`.  Since mainstream support for Vista was dropped in 2012 and (at this moment) only about [1⅔% of web-browsing machines are Vista](http://www.netmarketshare.com/report.aspx?qprid=11&qpaf=&qpcustom=Windows+Vista&qpcustomb=0), I'm not particularly inclined to restore the C# failover code to this answer.  I [added it as a new answer for you](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36156326/1683264), though.

Comment: @rojo I can't thank you enough for your time and how helpful you have been. it's been working great these past days. saved so much time. tonight while I was feeding it more files it outputted with a missing character so I did a dummy file pinpointed it to the exclamation mark !. is there anyway around this?

Comment: @xNightmare67x Disable delayed expansion before the activating the chooser.

Comment: That solved the issue.sorry for bothering you so many times. :)

Comment: I want to run a command when the user clicks on the cancel button on the folder chooser dialog box. How do I do it?

Comment: @Xiam You could replace `echo You chose %%~I` with something like `set "choice=%%~I"` and then `if not defined choice ( command )` or similar.  If you can't figure it out, create a new question post and show what you've tried that doesn't work, and explain the errors you get or how the script behaves differently from what you expect.

Comment: Hey does anyone know how I can modify this to have the all files option as well as any image type option? (e.g. .jpg, .png, .bmp)?

Comment: @MarkDeven You can use multiple file mask patterns in a single option by separating the file masks with semicolons. Example: `$f.Filter = "Image Files (*.jpg, *.png, *.gif, *.bmp, *.tif)|*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png;*.gif;*.bmp;*.tif|All Files (*.*)|*.*"` See the remarks section of [FileDialog.Filter Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filter?view=netframework-4.7.2) for full details.

Comment: What about WinPE?

Comment: My antivirus thinks this is a trojan :)

Comment: This does not work if a folder has whitespace like Alpha Tauri or something. How to do it then?

Answer (score 15):

This should work from XP upwards and does'nt require an hibrid file, it just runs mshta with a long command line:

```
@echo off
set dialog="about:<input type=file id=FILE><script>FILE.click();new ActiveXObject
set dialog=%dialog%('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1).WriteLine(FILE.value);
set dialog=%dialog%close();resizeTo(0,0);</script>"

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%p in ('mshta.exe %dialog%') do set "file=%%p"
echo selected  file is : "%file%"
pause
```

Comment: Notice it opens a regular Explorer File Slector dialog. The title of the dialog can't be changed with this method.

Comment: Is it possible to have this with multiple selection ?

Comment: Found it with powershell: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52240766/how-to-select-multiple-files-using-the-batch-selector

Comment: What would a folder selector be?

Answer (score 11):

## Windows Script Host

---

#### File Selection

Windows XP had a mysterious `UserAccounts.CommonDialog` WSH object [which allowed VBScript](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/vbstech_ui_fileopen.php) and JScript to launch the file selection prompt.  Apparently, that was [deemed a security risk](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2009/05/15/quick-hits-friday-the-scripting-guys-respond-to-a-bunch-of-questions-05-15-09.aspx#EYAAC) and removed in Vista.

---

#### Folder Selection

However, the WSH Shell.Application object [BrowseForFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774065%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method will still allow the creation of a folder selection dialog.  Here's a hybrid batch + JScript example.  Save it with a `.bat` extension.

```
@if (@a==@b) @end /*

:: fchooser2.bat
:: batch portion

@echo off
setlocal

for /f "delims=" %%I in ('cscript /nologo /e:jscript "%~f0"') do (
    echo You chose %%I
)

goto :EOF

:: JScript portion */

var shl = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");
var folder = shl.BrowseForFolder(0, "Please choose a folder.", 0, 0x00);
WSH.Echo(folder ? folder.self.path : '');
```

[image: folder selection dialog]

In the `BrowseForFolder()` method, the fourth argument specifies the root of the hierarchy.  See [ShellSpecialFolderConstants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774096%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for a list of valid values.

Answer (score 8):

A file / folder selection may be done with pure Batch, as shown below. Of course, the feel and look is not as pleasant as a GUI, but it works very well and in my opinion it is easier to use than the GUI version. The selection method is based on CHOICE command, so it would require to download it in the Windows versions that don't include it and slightly modify its parameters. Of course, the code may be easily modified in order to use SET /P instead of CHOICE, but this change would eliminate the very simple and fast selection method that only requires one keypress to navigate and select.

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem Select a file or folder browsing a directory tree
rem Antonio Perez Ayala

rem Usage examples of SelectFileOrFolder subroutine:

call :SelectFileOrFolder file=
echo/
echo Selected file from *.* = "%file%"
pause

call :SelectFileOrFolder file=*.bat
echo/
echo Selected Batch file = "%file%"
pause

call :SelectFileOrFolder folder=/F
echo/
echo Selected folder = "%folder%"
pause

goto :EOF


:SelectFileOrFolder resultVar [ "list of wildcards" | /F ]

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Process parameters
set "files=*.*"
if "%~2" neq "" (
   if /I "%~2" equ "/F" (set "files=") else set "files=%~2"
)

rem Set the number of lines per page, max 34
set "pageSize=30"
set "char=0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

rem Load current directory contents
set "name[1]=<DIR>  .."
:ProcessThisDir
set "numNames=1"
for /D %%a in (*) do (
   set /A numNames+=1
   set "name[!numNames!]=<DIR>  %%a"
)
for %%a in (%files%) do (
   set /A numNames+=1
   set "name[!numNames!]=       %%a"
)
set /A numPages=(numNames-1)/pageSize+1

rem Show directory contents, one page at a time
set start=1
:ShowPage
set /A page=(start-1)/pageSize+1, end=start+pageSize-1
if %end% gtr %numNames% set end=%numNames%
cls
echo Page %page%/%numPages% of %CD%
echo/
if %start% equ 1 (set base=0) else set "base=1"
set /A lastOpt=pageSize+base, j=base
for /L %%i in (%start%,1,%end%) do (
   for %%j in (!j!) do echo     !char:~%%j,1! -  !name[%%i]!
   set /A j+=1
)
echo/

rem Assemble the get option message
if %start% equ 1 (set "mssg=: ") else (set "mssg= (0=Previous page")
if %end% lss %numNames% (
   if "%mssg%" equ ": " (set "mssg= (") else set "mssg=%mssg%, "
   set "mssg=!mssg!Z=Next page"
)
if "%mssg%" neq ": " set "mssg=%mssg%): "

:GetOption
choice /C "%char%" /N /M "Select desired item%mssg%"
if %errorlevel% equ 1 (
   rem "0": Previous page or Parent directory
   if %start% gtr 1 (
      set /A start-=pageSize
      goto ShowPage
   ) else (
      cd ..
      goto ProcessThisDir
   )
)
if %errorlevel% equ 36 (
   rem "Z": Next page, if any
   if %end% lss %numNames% (
      set /A start+=pageSize
      goto ShowPage
   ) else (
      goto GetOption
   )
)
if %errorlevel% gtr %lastOpt% goto GetOption
set /A option=start+%errorlevel%-1-base
if %option% gtr %numNames% goto GetOption
if defined files (
   if "!name[%option%]:~0,5!" neq "<DIR>" goto endSelect
) else (
   choice /C OS /M "Open or Select '!name[%option%]:~7!' folder"
   if errorlevel 2 goto endSelect
)
cd "!name[%option%]:~7!"
goto ProcessThisDir

:endSelect
rem Return selected file/folder
for %%a in ("!name[%option%]:~7!") do set "result=%%~Fa"
endlocal & set "%~1=%result%
exit /B
```

Comment: can this be adjusted to allow navigating to external hard drives?

Comment: To change directory, just add cd statement somewhere in the beginning of this file. You can pass an variable to this bat file that contains a path. And then in the beginning of this bat file, add an if else statement like: `if "%~1" neq "" cd "%~1"`

Comment: or this `if "%~1" neq ""  if exist "%~1\*" (cd "%~1")` to check and make sure that path exists before you `cd` it

Answer (score 7):

Other solution with direct run PowerShell command in Batch

```
rem preparation command
set pwshcmd=powershell -noprofile -command "&{[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.windows.forms') | Out-Null;$OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog; $OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog()|out-null; $OpenFileDialog.FileName}"

rem exec commands powershell and get result in FileName variable
for /f "delims=" %%I in ('%pwshcmd%') do set "FileName=%%I"

echo %FileName%
```

Comment: Is it possible to have this with a multiple selection ?

Comment: Found it : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52240766/how-to-select-multiple-files-using-the-batch-selector

Answer (score 6):

#### Batch + PowerShell + C# polyglot solution

This is the same solution as the [Batch + PowerShell hybrid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15885133/1683264), but with the C# fallback stuff re-added for XP and Vista compatibility.  Multiple file selection has been added at [xNightmare67x's request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15885132/file-folder-chooser-dialog-from-a-windows-batch-script/15885133#comment59928413_15885133).

```js
<# : chooser_XP_Vista.bat
:: // launches a File... Open sort of file chooser and outputs choice(s) to the console
:: // https://stackoverflow.com/a/36156326/1683264

@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

rem // Does powershell.exe exist within %PATH%?

for %%I in ("powershell.exe") do if "%%~$PATH:I" neq "" (
    set chooser=powershell -noprofile "iex (${%~f0} | out-string)"
) else (

    rem // If not, compose and link C# application to open file browser dialog

    set "chooser=%temp%\chooser.exe"

    >"%temp%\c.cs" (
        echo using System;
        echo using System.Windows.Forms;
        echo class dummy {
        echo    public static void Main^(^) {
        echo        OpenFileDialog f = new OpenFileDialog^(^);
        echo        f.InitialDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
        echo        f.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
        echo        f.ShowHelp = true;
        echo        f.Multiselect = true;
        echo        f.ShowDialog^(^);
        echo        foreach ^(String filename in f.FileNames^) {
        echo            Console.WriteLine^(filename^);
        echo        }
        echo    }
        echo }
    )
    for /f "delims=" %%I in ('dir /b /s "%windir%\microsoft.net\*csc.exe"') do (
        if not exist "!chooser!" "%%I" /nologo /out:"!chooser!" "%temp%\c.cs" 2>NUL
    )
    del "%temp%\c.cs"
    if not exist "!chooser!" (
        echo Error: Please install .NET 2.0 or newer, or install PowerShell.
        goto :EOF
    )
)

rem // Do something with the chosen file(s)
for /f "delims=" %%I in ('%chooser%') do (
    echo You chose %%~I
)

rem // comment this out to keep chooser.exe in %temp% for faster subsequent runs
del "%temp%\chooser.exe" >NUL 2>NUL

goto :EOF
:: // end Batch portion / begin PowerShell hybrid chimera #>

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$f = new-object Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
$f.InitialDirectory = pwd
$f.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*"
$f.ShowHelp = $true
$f.Multiselect = $true
[void]$f.ShowDialog()
if ($f.Multiselect) { $f.FileNames } else { $f.FileName }
```

---

For a folder chooser for XP or Vista, use either the [WSH solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15906994/1683264) or [npocmaka's HTA solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24415437/1683264).

Answer (score 3):

Two more ways.

1.Using a hybrid .bat/hta (must be saved as a `bat`) script .It can use vbscript or javascript but the example is with javascrtipt.Does not create temp files.Selecting folder is not so easy and will require an external javascript libraries , but selecting file is easy

```
<!-- : starting html comment

:: FileSelector.bat
@echo off
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%p in ('mshta.exe "%~f0"') do (
    set "file=%%~fp"
)
echo/
if not "%file%" == "" (
    echo selected  file is : %file%
)
echo/
exit /b
-->
<Title>== FILE SELECTOR==</Title>
<body>
    <script language='javascript'>
    function pipeFile() {

         var file=document.getElementById('file').value;
         var fso= new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1);
         close(fso.Write(file));

    }
    </script>
<input type='file' name='file' size='30'>
</input><hr><button onclick='pipeFile()'>Submit</button>
</body>
```

1.1 - without submit form proposed by rojo (see comments):

```
<!-- : starting html comment

:: FileSelector.bat
@echo off
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%p in ('mshta.exe "%~f0"') do (
    set "file=%%~fp"
)
echo/
if not "%file%" == "" (
    echo selected  file is : "%file%"
)
echo/
exit /b
-->
<Title>== FILE SELECTOR==</Title>
<body>
    <script language='javascript'>
    function pipeFile() {

         var file=document.getElementById('file').value;
         var fso= new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1);
         close(fso.Write(file));

    }
    </script>
<input id='file' type='file' name='file' size='30' onchange='pipeFile()' >
</input>
<hr>
<button onclick='pipeFile()'>Submit</button>
<script>document.getElementById('file').click();</script>
</body>
```

2.As you already using powershell/net you can create selfcompiled jscript.net hybrid.It will not require temp cs file for compilation and will directly use the built-in jscrript.net compiler.There's no need of powershell too and the code is far more readable:

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /* JScript comment
@echo off

:: FolderSelectorJS.bat
setlocal

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%v in ('dir /b /s /a:-d  /o:-n "%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\*jsc.exe"') do (
   set "jsc=%%v"
)

if not exist "%~n0.exe" (
    "%jsc%" /nologo /out:"%~n0.exe" "%~dpsfnx0"
)

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%p in ('"%~n0.exe"') do (
    set "folder=%%p"
)
if not "%folder%" == "" ( 
    echo selected folder  is %folder%
)

endlocal & exit /b %errorlevel%

*/

import System;
import System.Windows.Forms;

var  f=new FolderBrowserDialog();
f.SelectedPath=System.Environment.CurrentDirectory;
f.Description="Please choose a folder.";
f.ShowNewFolderButton=true;
if( f.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK ){
    Console.Write(f.SelectedPath);
}
```

Comment: Suggestions for your HTA hybrid:  add `id='file'` to the `<input>` tag, add `onchange='pipeFile()'` to the `<input>` tag, and add `<script>document.getElementById('file').click();</script>` just above `</body>`.

Answer (score 1):

I will leave an 'echo' even to verify that multiple choice works in this code

```
echo off
set cmd=Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms;$f=new-object                 Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog;$f.InitialDirectory=        [environment]::GetFolderPath('Desktop');$f.Filter='Text Files(*.txt)^|*.txt^|All         Files(*.*)^|*.*';$f.Multiselect=$true;[void]$f.ShowDialog();if($f.Multiselect)        {$f.FileNames}else{$f.FileName}
set pwshcmd=powershell -noprofile -command "&{%cmd%}"
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%I in ('%pwshcmd%') do call :sum "%%I" ret
echo =========
echo --%ret%--
pause
exit /B
:sum [mud] [ret]
echo "%~1"
set FileName=%FileName% "%~1"
set ret=%FileName%
exit /B
```

Comment: Although I suggest to have: 1) `exit /B` before `:sum` and 2) have `goto :eof` at the end of `:sum`. Or else `:sum` runs twice

Answer (score 0):

I has been wrote my own portable solution:
https://github.com/andry81/contools/tree/HEAD/Utilities/src/_gui/wxFileDialog/

You can download executable from here:
https://github.com/andry81/contools/tree/HEAD/Utilities/bin/contools/wxFileDialog.exe

The utility has dependency on wxWidgets 3.1.x, so you can actually build it for other operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

rojo, thanks for the code. It works.

A small note:
For the "Browse for Folder" code, a user may click the X and NOT select a folder at all. For this case, I would add:

```
if not defined folder (goto :noFolderSelected)
```

Also, for the BrowseForFolder() method, I recommend the 4th argument to be **0x11**. This will display all drives.