# Batch File/Specifying File Paths

Tags: file, batch-file

I've made a Program that Launches other programs, but here is the problem.
You need to specify the path of the file in the code which means that the end-user needs to get into the code to specify the file which is not really the ideal situation.

I have solution in mind,when you launch the program a dialog box comes up and asks you to give it the file path so it can run the specified program. How would I go about doing something like this?

Comment: Do you mind if the path is passed as a parameter instead of a dialogbox? e.g. `yourprogram.exe <path/of/file>`

Comment: No I don't mind if the path is passed as a parameter.

Comment: [File / folder chooser dialog from a Windows batch script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15885132/file-folder-chooser-dialog-from-a-windows-batch-script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also do the following

```
@echo off
set foo=%1
echo %foo%
```

`%1` refers to the 1st parameter that you have passed it to the program. This first parameter will then be set to the variable `%foo%`. Here is the example:

```
C:\>test.bat "C:\passwd"
C:\passwd
```

Hope this helps :)

**Update**

You can make your program to execute another program by doing the following:

```
@echo off

REM `%~f1` will helps to expand `%1` to a fully qualitified path name
set "executable=%~f1"

REM checks if the first parameter exist. If it did not exist, a usage text will be displayed and the program will exit
if "%executable%"=="" (
    echo Usage: %0 path\to\executable
    goto :EOF
) else (
    call :program
    goto :EOF
)

:program
echo %executable% is starting...
start "" "%executable%"
goto :EOF
```

Comment: Thanks this and the other comment gave me an idea of how to do it, if I could I would tick both as correct :)

Comment: I'm now confused again, could you possibly show this in an example? :)

Comment: it is actually the same. All you have to do is to save the script and try running it in command prompt :)

Comment: Okay, now I understand that part, the other part i'm confused about is how i would put this into my code? So the user can declare the path that the program must go to , to open the file/script/program.

Comment: Thank's this is perfect :D

Answer (score 0):

You can reads user input. e.g. edit the following snippet according to you need

```
ECHO User will have to enter the input file path.
set /p variable=Enter input files path please:
```

The user can type as many letters as they want, and it will go into the delBuild variable.

Comment: Thanks, please could you explain to me exactly what the delBuild variable is? I'm sort of new to batch :/

Comment: It means that the user input will be stored to variable delBuild

Comment: On second thought could you try to give me an Example? :)

Comment: The command set /p reads whatever the user types, whether it be one letter or multiple.