# How to create a batch file to run a jar file that is in any location of the system

Tags: java, batch-file, jar

I have a MyFile.jar file. I need a batch file that searches for the jar file and triggers it.

I found the following solution. But for that batch file and jar file must be in the same folder.

```
java -jar %~dp0MyFile.jar %*
```

We don't know where the client will place jar file in their system. But they will put batch file in startup folder.

Edit: I managed to write this batch file for now.

```
`ECHO
 ECHO Locating the Jar

 IF EXIST java -jar MyFile.jar  ELSE (GOTO 

 SearchJar)

:SearchJar
SET the_path=D: & CD\
DIR /S/B File.jar > installer_location.txt
SET /P the_path=< installer_location.txt
if defined the_path goto :FoundIt

E: & CD\
DIR /S/B MyFile.jar > installer_location.txt
SET /P the_path=< installer_location.txt
if defined the_path goto :FoundIt

C: & CD\
DIR /S/B MyFile.jar > installer_location.txt
SET /P the_path=< installer_location.txt
if defined the_path goto :FoundIt

G: & CD\
DIR /S/B MyFile.jar > installer_location.txt
SET /P the_path=< installer_location.txt
if defined the_path goto :FoundIt

H: & CD\
DIR /S/B MyFile.jar > installer_location.txt
SET /P the_path=< installer_location.txt
if defined the_path goto :FoundIt

I: & CD\
DIR /S/B MyFile.jar > installer_location.txt
SET /P the_path=< installer_location.txt
if defined the_path goto :FoundIt
ECHO Jar not found.

:FoundIt
ECHO Jar file found at %the_path%

CALL java -jar %the_path%`
```

This is working now in my system. But I am not sure if there will be a simpler way to check all the drives at once.

Comment: This is not a reasonable request. If you are requiring the client to place a batch file in their startup folder, why not require them to place the jar file in their startup folder instead? With a batch file, you must know where the jar file is located in the file system, whether by an environment variable, or by a file system search (very slow), or by requiring it to be in a specific place. The best practice is to use installation software such as InstallShield.

Comment: If you put the jar file where the batch file is, the code you posted will work because `%~dp0` will evaluate to whatever directory the batch file is in. You should put it in double quotes though: `" %~dp0MyFile.jar"` in case the directory contains spaces.

Comment: Can we not make a batch file that searches for the jar file in the system and runs it? like I mentioned in my question,  java -jar %~dp0MyFile.jar %* searches for its(batch file's) location and change the path to the batch file location and runs the jar file. Is there a way we can make the batch file serach for jar now?

Comment: Your code does **not** change "*the path to the batch file location*". It merely calls `java.exe` with a complete path to the jar file.

Comment: Okay,got it. But Still I din't get the answer I am looking for. Is there a way, batch file searches for jar file and calls java.exe with a complete path to the jar file?

Comment: You say you don't know where the client will place the jar file.  Does the client know where the client will place the jar file?  I propose adding a gui file chooser to your script and prompting the user for the location of the jar file.  Once you have it, save the location to the registry so you can retrieve it on subsequent runs.  If the reg key does not exist or if its value points to an erroneous location, file chooser again.  This will result in a better experience for the user, especially if the pc has multiple drives and puts the jar on d: or e:.  A search will take too long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First find the file and set a variable to its path, then use that variable as the path you want.  From your use of %~dp0, I assume you are working on windows only, so the following example is for windows

```
echo off
for /r C:\search_folder_root %%a in (*) do if "%%~nxa"=="MyFile.jar" set jarLoc=%%~dpa
java -jar %jarLoc%MyFile.jar %*
```

Be warned - the search could take quite a long time e.g. if you search a whole drive...

***EDIT:***

In response to OPs comments requesting a script that will search any drive on the system, here it is.  Please note - I don't think use of this is a good idea for user experience - it will be very inefficient and it could take ages...  Tested on a very simple case with a dummy jar on a path that occurs early in the search on my machine.  Note - if the user will know which drive the jar is on, or even better the path, you could always prompt them to enter that drive / path instead of looping through.

```
echo off
setlocal
set jarName=MyFile.jar

rem -- loop through each drive on system --
for /F "usebackq skip=1" %%i in (`wmic logicaldisk get caption 2^>NUL`) do (
  echo Checking drive %%i for %jarName%

  rem -- temporarily change to the drive --
  pushd %%i\

  rem -- recursively loop through every file of every subdirectory on that drive --
  for /r %%a in (*) do (
    if "%%~nxa"=="%jarName%" set jarLoc=%%~dpa
    if defined jarLoc goto :Found
  )
  popd
)

rem -- if we get to here, the jar has not been found --

echo %jarName% not found on any drive in this system
goto :eof

:Found
echo Jar found at %jarLoc%
popd
java -jar %jarLoc%%jarName% %*
```

Comment: I will try this again tomorrow and let you know if this worked. But before that, I tried something and I need a simpler solution for the following file. I may not be able to post this here. will edit my post with the batch file i wrote. Please check that.

Comment: Yes, I am working on Windows and also does the batch file u gave searches all the drives in the system or just the C drive? Thanks :)

Comment: The original answer just searched through the drive given.  In response to your comment I've added an example to go through all drives on a system.  It's a slightly neater way to go through the drives (in my opinion) and doesn't require pre-knowledge of drive letters (e.g. jar could be on a pen drive or unusually lettered network drive).  Note though - this could give terrible user experience as it's likely to go REALLY slow.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks :). You know Snr Management.. They just need answer. Then the cons. Now I have both answer and the cons :) :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

As gknicker and I commented above, this is the way it should be done.  If you used an installer (like NSIS or similar) to deploy the `.jar` file and `.bat` script, have the installer write the registry value, and a search or file browse may never be needed.  If the `.jar` file is moved after installation, pop up a [GUI file chooser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15885132/) and let the user browse to the location he saved `MyFile.jar`.  Save the updated location to the registry.  Re-prompt if the file is moved again.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "jarfile=MyFile.jar"
set "regkey=HKLM\Software\Company Name"
set "regvalue=jarfile"

set jarpath=
for /f "tokens=2*" %%I in ('reg query "%regkey%" /v "%regvalue%" 2^>NUL') do (
    set "jarpath=%%~J"
)

if not exist "%jarpath%" (
    call :chooser jarpath "%jarfile%" "%jarfile% (*.jar)|*.jar"
)

if exist "%jarpath%" (
    reg add "%regkey%" /v "%regvalue%" /t REG_SZ /d "%jarpath%" /f 2>&1>NUL
) else (
    <NUL set /P "=Unable to locate %jarfile%.  This thread will self-destruct in 5 seconds... "
    ping -n 6 0.0.0.0 >NUL
    echo bang.
    exit /b 1
)

java -jar "%jarpath%"

goto :EOF

:chooser <var_to_set> <filename> <filter>
:: based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15885132

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
:: Does powershell.exe exist within %PATH%?
for %%I in (powershell.exe) do if "%%~$PATH:I" neq "" (
    set chooser=powershell "Add-Type -AssemblyName System.windows.forms|Out-Null;$f=New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog;$f.InitialDirectory='%cd%';$f.Filter='%~3';$f.showHelp=$true;$f.Title='Locate %~2';$f.ShowDialog()|Out-Null;$f.FileName"
) else (
rem :: If not, compose and link C# application to open file browser dialog
    set chooser=%temp%\chooser.exe
    >"%temp%\c.cs" echo using System;using System.Windows.Forms;
    >>"%temp%\c.cs" echo class dummy{
    >>"%temp%\c.cs" echo public static void Main^(^){
    >>"%temp%\c.cs" echo OpenFileDialog f=new OpenFileDialog^(^);
    >>"%temp%\c.cs" echo f.InitialDirectory=Environment.CurrentDirectory;
    >>"%temp%\c.cs" echo f.Filter="%~3";
    >>"%temp%\c.cs" echo f.ShowHelp=true;
    >>"%temp%\c.cs" echo f.Title="Locate %~2";
    >>"%temp%\c.cs" echo f.ShowDialog^(^);
    >>"%temp%\c.cs" echo Console.Write^(f.FileName^);}}
    for /f "delims=" %%I in ('dir /b /s "%windir%\microsoft.net\*csc.exe"') do (
        if not exist "!chooser!" "%%I" /nologo /out:"!chooser!" "%temp%\c.cs" 2>NUL
    )
    del "%temp%\c.cs"
    if not exist "!chooser!" (
        echo Error: Please install .NET 2.0 or newer, or install PowerShell.
        goto :EOF
    )
)

:: capture choice to a variable
endlocal && for /f "delims=" %%I in ('%chooser%') do set "%~1=%%I"

:: Clean up the mess
del "%temp%\chooser.exe" 2>NUL
goto :EOF
```

---

If you insist on searching all local drives for `MyFile.jar`, you can query a drive list with `wmic logicaldisk`.  Exclude network drives by adding `where "not drivetype=4"`.  You should still save the result to the registry to prevent a several minute delay on every run.

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "jarfile=MyFile.jar"
set "regkey=HKLM\Software\Company Name"
set "regvalue=jarfile"

set jarpath=
for /f "tokens=2*" %%I in ('reg query "%regkey%" /v "%regvalue%" 2^>NUL') do (
    set "jarpath=%%~J"
)

if not exist "%jarpath%" (
    call :finder jarpath "%jarfile%"
)

if exist "%jarpath%" (
    reg add "%regkey%" /v "%regvalue%" /t REG_SZ /d "%jarpath%" /f 2>&1>NUL
) else (
    <NUL set /P "=Unable to locate %jarfile%.  This thread will self-destruct in 5 seconds... "
    ping -n 6 0.0.0.0 >NUL
    echo bang.
    exit /b 1
)

java -jar "%jarpath%"

goto :EOF

:finder <var_to_set> <file_to_find>
setlocal
:: in wmic, drivetype=4 is network drive
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:=" %%I in (
    'wmic logicaldisk where "not drivetype=4" get DeviceID /format:list ^| find "="'
) do (
    <NUL set /P "=Searching %%I: for %~2... "
    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /s /b "%%I:\*%~2"') do (
        echo %%~dpa
        endlocal & set "%~1=%%a"
        goto :EOF
    )
    echo Not found.
)
goto :EOF
```