# Calling a batch script to run code from a browser?

Tags: user-interface, batch-file

I have a batch script that run SAS. I want to build a GUI around that script so rather than manually typing in the path of the source directory and the parameters I want to pass to SAS, I just click my options.

I thought about doing this in via Javascript but am not sure if I can run a custom batch command using that? Any recommendations?

Everything would be local, the html file, the .bat and the SAS installation.

Thanks!

Comment: You might be able to communicate between batch and an HTA file to accomplish what you want.  npocmaka posted a [lovely batch + HTA hybrid](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24415437/1683264) that might give you a basic framework on which to build.  The key is to push the user selection to a `Scripting.FileSystemObject` COM object's `.GetStandardStream(1)` method, then capture it with a `for /f` loop back on the batch side.

Comment: See [this post](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6342&p=40794#p40794). It may give you some ideas...