# Batch script CDing to wrong file location

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have the following code snippet:

```
   @echo off 

for %%d in (c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do (
  if exist "%%d:\Program Files (x86)\location\folder" (
    cd /d "%%d:\Program Files (x86)\location\folder"
  ) else cd /d "%%d:\location\folder\" 2>nul && goto :break

)

::display error message if folder not found
:break
if %errorlevel% equ 0 (
    echo "Folder found, going to folder location"
) else (
    set /p location=Could not find folder. Please enter folder location: 
    cd %location%
    echo %location%
)
```

For some reason, when I give it location to CD to, the first time it CDs to the wrong file location. If I run the code snippet again from the same command line, it CDs to the previously given file location. Any reason this could be?

Answer (score 0):

you need [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html):

```
::display error message if folder not found
:break
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
if %errorlevel% equ 0 (
    echo "Folder found, going to folder location"
) else (
    set /p location="Could not find folder. Please enter folder location: "
    cd /d "!location!"
)
```

better use cd with `/d` switch if there's a chance of drive jumping

**EDIT** try this (not tested):

```
   @echo off 

for %%d in (c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do (
  if exist "%%d:\Program Files (x86)\location\folder" (
    cd /d "%%d:\Program Files (x86)\location\folder"
  ) else (
    cd /d "%%d:\location\folder\" 2>nul && goto :break
  )

)


for %%d in (c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do (
  if exist "%%d:\Program Files (x86)\location\folder" (
    cd /d "%%d:\Program Files (x86)\location\folder"
    goto :break
  )
)

for %%d in (c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do (
  if exist "%%d:\location\folder\" (
    cd /d "%%d:\location\folder\"
    goto :break
  )
)

:retry
set /p "location=Could not find folder. Please enter folder location: "
cd /d "%location%"  2>nul || (
  echo wrong location
  echo try again
  goto :retry
)
echo %location%
goto :break



::display error message if folder not found

echo "Folder found, going to folder location"

exit /b 0
```

Comment: When I use this version, it jumps to 'folder found...' even if the folder is not found.

Comment: @VioletSmith What's in the rest of your code? Here's there's  nothing that could tell me what and how sets the error level

Comment: @VioletSmith - check also this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15885132/file-folder-chooser-dialog-from-a-windows-batch-script