# Batch Code explanation

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I found this code online, and it allows me to choose a folder using a GUI. Can someone please explain to me how this works, and how I can get an output from it. I am hoping I can get an output and assign that to a variable.

NOTE: I did NOT make this. I simply found it online at another stack overflow post.

```
:: fchooser.bat
:: launches a folder chooser and outputs choice to the console
:: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15885133/1683264

@echo off
setlocal

set "psCommand="(new-object -COM 'Shell.Application')^
.BrowseForFolder(0,'Please choose a folder.',0,0).self.path""

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%I in (`powershell %psCommand%`) do set "folder=%%I"

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
echo You chose !folder!
endlocal
```

Thanks a lot,
ChapelCone56

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set "psCommand="(new-object -COM 'Shell.Application')^.BrowseForFolder(0,'Please choose a folder.',0,0).self.path""
```

It is creating a new powershell object for windows to invoke the browse folder dialogue

```
FOR /F
```

Loop command  against the results of other command.

```
usebackq
```

use the different quoting style

```
powershell %psCommand%
```

creates a pipileline that another object can use

```
set "folder=%%I"
```

setting folder variable to the choosen folder name

```
echo You chose !folder!
```

display the choice

if you want to use the selected folder name, use variable **folder** whose value can be found as **!folder!**