# Windows batch file browser

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, browser

So I'm trying to make a Windows batch file that will open the file dialog and allow me to select multiple files that will echo the file names to a txt file. I did some research and manged to find part of the answer here

[link to the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15885132/file-folder-chooser-dialog-from-a-windows-batch-script)

However that only allows me to select one file at a time. a user in the comments was able to make it select multiple files however there is no info on how. thanks for your time and hope you can help.

Comment: Are you referring to the top answer, as how you wish to implement?

Comment: [Literally the third sentence.](http://i.imgur.com/Y1r8a8o.png)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36156326/1683264

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to [MultiSelect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.multiselect.aspx).

```
>>"%temp%\c.cs" echo class dummy{
>>"%temp%\c.cs" echo public static void Main^(^){
>>"%temp%\c.cs" echo OpenFileDialog f=new OpenFileDialog^(^);
>>"%temp%\c.cs" echo f.InitialDirectory=Environment.CurrentDirectory;
>>"%temp%\c.cs" echo f.Filter="Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
>>"%temp%\c.cs" echo f.Multiselect = true;
>>"%temp%\c.cs" echo f.ShowHelp=true;
>>"%temp%\c.cs" echo f.ShowDialog^(^);
>>"%temp%\c.cs" echo foreach^(var filename in f.FileNames^)
>>"%temp%\c.cs" echo Console.Write^(filename^ + "\t");}}
```

Not sure how you want to use it, but just modify the code to do what you wish with the output.