# Unable to pass variable (path) from user input in vbs to batch command for deleting Thumbs.db

Tags: batch-file

Here is my code (delete_thumbs.vbs):

```
Dim str
str = InputBox("Enter the path from where you want to delete thumbs")
Dim oShell
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
oShell.run "cmd /K CD /d & str"
```

I am willing to get the user input for the path of the folder by prompting them to enter the path using InputBox and then execute a command to delete all the Thumbs.db located in that folder.

Command to delete Thumbs.db

```
del /s /q /f /a:h Thumbs.db
```

The problem I am facing is that when I run "delete_thumbs.vbs" it prompts for user input to enter path of the folder but after the path is entered its not getting detected in CMD and it just prompts:

```
The system can not find the path specified

C:/Users/user/Desktop
```

Please guide me.Where am I going wrong

Comment: may you'll want to check this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15885132/file-folder-chooser-dialog-from-a-windows-batch-script

Comment: Shouldn't it be more like   `oShell.run "cmd /K CD /d " & str`  if you are trying to add the content of the variable `str` to the command?  But why use a batch command in the first place?

Comment: After I delete thumbs from the folder I need to run a sync program Synctoy thats why I decided to use batch command.

I edited as Fred suggested. Now I am able to directly reach to the folder path given by user:

For example:

D:/Data/Volume1>

Comment: Now one last step is pending, that is to enter the command (del /s /q /f /a:h Thumbs.db) to delete thumbs.db in that folder. 

How can I do that?

I tried by doing this and several other methods:

{oShell.run "cmd /K CD /d" & str & del /s /q /f /a:h Thumbs.db}

But its not working.

Comment: Can somebody please help me resolve this. I really need your help.