# Concatenate output of file dialog in 1 string

Tags: batch-file

I am getting crazy to do something that shall be relatively easy...
I am using the code in [File / folder chooser dialog from a Windows batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15885132/file-folder-chooser-dialog-from-a-windows-batch-script) in a bat file to open the file dialog and let the user select multiple files.
What I need to do next is to concatenate the result of the selection in a single string to pass as parameters to another application. I am failing to concatenate the strings...

What I have is:

```
<# : chooser.bat
:: launches a File... Open sort of file chooser and outputs choice(s) to the console
:: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15885133/1683264

@echo off
setlocal

set slctn=

for /f "delims=" %%I in ('powershell -noprofile "iex (${%~f0} | out-string)"') do (
    echo You chose %%~I
    set slctn=!slctn!|%%~I
)

REM here use %slctn% in another command
echo %slctn%
goto :EOF

: end Batch portion / begin PowerShell hybrid chimera #>

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$f = new-object Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
$f.InitialDirectory = "C:\Users\Public\Documents\MCI\Sito Web"
$f.Title = "Seleft PDF files to merge"
$f.Filter = "PDF Files (*.pdf)|*.pdf|All Files (*.*)|*.*"
$f.ShowHelp = $true
$f.Multiselect = $true
[void]$f.ShowDialog()
if ($f.Multiselect) { $f.FileNames } else { $f.FileName }
```

And the result I get is:

```
C:\Users\Public\Documents\MCI\Sito Web\Insieme>MergePDFInsieme
You chose C:\Users\Public\Documents\MCI\Sito Web\Ristorante\2016-02-08\menugiornaliero.pdf
'C:\Users\Public\Documents\MCI\Sito' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Public\Documents\MCI\Sito Web\Insieme>
```

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is the pipesymbol (`|`), which is executed by the parser. `set slctn=!slctn!|%%~I` gives you an errormessage, because it gets parsed as `set slctn=!slctn!` and pipes it's output (which is empty) to another command, which in this case is the content of `%%I`.

You can set your variable like this: `set "slctn=!slctn!|%%~I"` (you can verify with `set slctn`).

But you will fall into the same problem with your line `echo %slctn%`. You have to use qoutes around the string to echo it properly: `echo "%slctn%"`.
If showing quotes is not an option, it gets a bit more complicated:
`for %%i in ("%slctn%") do echo %%~i`

Comment: The other option is to use delayed expansion when displaying the value. But the OP should be aware that variables have a max length <8191 bytes.

Comment: Thanks, almost perfect... now I do not get the error any longer, but the variable reading is not working as expected, I get `C:\Users\Public\Documents\MCI\Sito Web\Insieme>MergePDFInsieme.cmd
You chose C:\Users\Public\Documents\MCI\Sito Web\Ristorante\2016-02-15\menugiornaliero.pdf
You chose C:\Users\Public\Documents\MCI\Sito Web\Ristorante\2016-02-15\specialitasettimana.pdf
"!slctn!|C:\Users\Public\Documents\MCI\Sito Web\Ristorante\2016-02-15\specialitasettimana.pdf"`

Comment: by adding the `EnableDelayedExpansion` the answer worked completely.