# Windows Batch Files: How to remember the user Input

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to create a Windows Batch File that can remember what user type for a short time.

I mean when I click my .BAT File, It should ask like `Please enter your program installation directory`.

if user types nothing the batch file should exit otherwise it should set the text (The installation directory in my case)that user typed before to a variable like `%DIRECTORY%`.

From there, the `%DIRECTORY%` should behave like a variable and should has the ability to be mentioned like `cd %DIRECTORY` , `COPY %DIRECTORY/MyApp.exe` in next commands I use.

How can I do this?

I also tried to do this:

```
@echo off
color 1E
title TESTING BATCH FILE
echo Enter your APP INSTALLATION DIRECTORY.  
echo.
echo.
set /p DIR=ENTER THE INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: <<<Prompting From The User>>>
echo DIRECTORY="%DIR%" <<<Set what user typed as a variable>>>
cd %DIR% <<<Execute further commands using it>>>
pause
exit
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: why have %DIRECTORY%? You've already got the exact same information in %DIR%, which is where `set /p` put the user input. and you can't set system-wide env vars from a cmd shell. that can only be done from the system control panel.

Comment: if you want to set a variable, then `set` it, don't `echo` it.

Comment: `set DIRECTORY="%DIR%"` <<<Set what user typed as a variable>>>

Comment: Also, rather than asking the user to type the directory location, you could have the user [browse for the directory to use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15885132/file-folder-chooser-dialog-from-a-windows-batch-script).

Comment: @rojo It worked well..........

Comment: @MarcB YES after getting information from `%DIR%` , I need it to be mentioned in some commands......how to do this?

Comment: @Aacini Yes the line you're showing is how I tried to make it a variable using `%%`

Comment: To store something in a user- or system-related environment variable permanently use `setx` (type `setx /?` for help)...

Comment: `setx` .......I never heard or tried this before........I will try to use this in commmands