# Browse option is not taking Shared Drive or UNC path

Tags: batch-file

I am taking the help of this link [Folder Selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15885132/file-folder-chooser-dialog-from-a-windows-batch-script/15906994#15906994)
but my shared path or any other UNC path is not appearing.

```
setlocal
set "psCommand="(new-object -COM 'Shell.Application')^.BrowseForFolder(0,'Please choose a folder.',0,0).self.path""

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%I in (`powershell %psCommand%`) do set "folder=%%I"

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
echo FolderPath !folder!
pause
endlocal
REM Ending Folder option

if not exist %folder% mkdir %folder%
set robocopy=robocopy /E

echo FolderPath **%folder%** <-- this 'folder' is not taking UNC/Shared path
%robocopy% "MyLocalDrive" %folder% <-- this 'folder'
```

Any suggestion

Comment: Why do you have the value of `psCommand` quoted (`""`)? I mean `set "psCommand="...""`; I would try `set "psCommand=..."`. In addition, change `robocopy "MyLocaldrive" %folder%` to `robocopy "MyLocalDrive" "%folder%"`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the Docs from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg537710(v=vs.85).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

```
IShellDispatch.BrowseForFolder( _
  ByVal Hwnd As Integer, _
  ByVal sTitle As BSTR, _
  ByVal iOptions As Integer, _
  [ ByVal vRootFolder As Variant ] _
) As FOLDER
```

and these are the flags see BIF_BROWSEINCLUDEURLS and  BIF_SHAREABLE

```
ulFlags
Type: UINT

Flags that specify the options for the dialog box. This member can be 0 or a combination of the following values. Version numbers refer to the minimum version of Shell32.dll required for SHBrowseForFolder to recognize flags added in later releases. See Shell and Common Controls Versions for more information.


BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS (0x00000001)

0x00000001. Only return file system directories. If the user selects folders that are not part of the file system, the OK button is grayed. 

Note  The OK button remains enabled for "\\server" items, as well as "\\server\share" and directory items. However, if the user selects a "\\server" item, passing the PIDL returned by SHBrowseForFolder to SHGetPathFromIDList fails.



BIF_DONTGOBELOWDOMAIN (0x00000002)

0x00000002. Do not include network folders below the domain level in the dialog box's tree view control.

BIF_STATUSTEXT (0x00000004)

0x00000004. Include a status area in the dialog box. The callback function can set the status text by sending messages to the dialog box. This flag is not supported when BIF_NEWDIALOGSTYLE is specified.

BIF_RETURNFSANCESTORS (0x00000008)

0x00000008. Only return file system ancestors. An ancestor is a subfolder that is beneath the root folder in the namespace hierarchy. If the user selects an ancestor of the root folder that is not part of the file system, the OK button is grayed.

BIF_EDITBOX (0x00000010)

0x00000010. Version 4.71. Include an edit control in the browse dialog box that allows the user to type the name of an item.

BIF_VALIDATE (0x00000020)

0x00000020. Version 4.71. If the user types an invalid name into the edit box, the browse dialog box calls the application's BrowseCallbackProc with the BFFM_VALIDATEFAILED message. This flag is ignored if BIF_EDITBOX is not specified.

BIF_NEWDIALOGSTYLE (0x00000040)

0x00000040. Version 5.0. Use the new user interface. Setting this flag provides the user with a larger dialog box that can be resized. The dialog box has several new capabilities, including: drag-and-drop capability within the dialog box, reordering, shortcut menus, new folders, delete, and other shortcut menu commands. 

Note  If COM is initialized through CoInitializeEx with the COINIT_MULTITHREADED flag set, SHBrowseForFolder fails if BIF_NEWDIALOGSTYLE is passed.



BIF_BROWSEINCLUDEURLS (0x00000080)

0x00000080. Version 5.0. The browse dialog box can display URLs. The BIF_USENEWUI and BIF_BROWSEINCLUDEFILES flags must also be set. If any of these three flags are not set, the browser dialog box rejects URLs. Even when these flags are set, the browse dialog box displays URLs only if the folder that contains the selected item supports URLs. When the folder's IShellFolder::GetAttributesOf method is called to request the selected item's attributes, the folder must set the SFGAO_FOLDER attribute flag. Otherwise, the browse dialog box will not display the URL.

BIF_USENEWUI

Version 5.0. Use the new user interface, including an edit box. This flag is equivalent to BIF_EDITBOX | BIF_NEWDIALOGSTYLE. 

Note  If COM is initialized through CoInitializeEx with the COINIT_MULTITHREADED flag set, SHBrowseForFolder fails if BIF_USENEWUI is passed.



BIF_UAHINT (0x00000100)

0x00000100. Version 6.0. When combined with BIF_NEWDIALOGSTYLE, adds a usage hint to the dialog box, in place of the edit box. BIF_EDITBOX overrides this flag.

BIF_NONEWFOLDERBUTTON (0x00000200)

0x00000200. Version 6.0. Do not include the New Folder button in the browse dialog box.

BIF_NOTRANSLATETARGETS (0x00000400)

0x00000400. Version 6.0. When the selected item is a shortcut, return the PIDL of the shortcut itself rather than its target.

BIF_BROWSEFORCOMPUTER (0x00001000)

0x00001000. Only return computers. If the user selects anything other than a computer, the OK button is grayed.

BIF_BROWSEFORPRINTER (0x00002000)

0x00002000. Only allow the selection of printers. If the user selects anything other than a printer, the OK button is grayed. 

In Windows XP and later systems, the best practice is to use a Windows XP-style dialog, setting the root of the dialog to the Printers and Faxes folder (CSIDL_PRINTERS).

BIF_BROWSEINCLUDEFILES (0x00004000)

0x00004000. Version 4.71. The browse dialog box displays files as well as folders.

BIF_SHAREABLE (0x00008000)

0x00008000. Version 5.0. The browse dialog box can display sharable resources on remote systems. This is intended for applications that want to expose remote shares on a local system. The BIF_NEWDIALOGSTYLE flag must also be set.

BIF_BROWSEFILEJUNCTIONS (0x00010000)

0x00010000. Windows 7 and later. Allow folder junctions such as a library or a compressed file with a .zip file name extension to be browsed.
```